# Related to gruntjs installation in MAC

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have been trying to install grunt in my mac. its gives the version correctly but when I run `grunt watch` or `grunt build` it gives be the error

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Please find the grunt file here I have tried uninstalling and installing again but it does not solve the issue

Comment: Please add your Gruntfile!

Comment: And read this: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: Please see the gruntfile

Comment: Well, apparently the problem could originate in your `package.json` file. Can you include that one also? Plus, I'm not completely sure whether you should be calling `require()` on that file in that way, although it appears to be OK. The error is related to the `paths` variable being null.

Comment: Please find my package.json below